# Kubernetes enable service for HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine with an application that has a public service endpoint. But I would like to change the endpoint from http://... to a secure https://.

What is the easiest way of going about this?

I assume I will need to somehow get an entity to issue me some sort of certificate for my domain. If that's the case, should I use the 35.X.X.X endpoint IP or use a domain such as mydomain.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Here are some:

1. An easy way is to create external layer 7 GCP load balancer and have it terminate your SSL, with your own certificates, then create a `NodePort` service to listen for your traffic (non-TLS) and forward the layer 7 load balancer to that `NodePort` on all your cluster machines. The downside of this solution would be that your internal cluster traffic would be non-TLS, but you may not care about that unless you are implementing compliance.

[image: LB]

2. Another way is to just let your application in the pod handle SSL directly and set the pod to listen on port 443 and expose it on your layer 4 GCP load balancer on port 443.
3. Another way (which is preferred on later Kubernetes versions) is to use the same `35.X.X.X` external IP which essentially is a layer 4 load balancer and have a [Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) listen for your traffic and handle [TLS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls).

Note that this all gets a bit trickier if you want to implement TLS end to end.

Comment: Is it also possible to just expose a new service on port 443? Also, what do you mean by a "layer X" load balancer and how do I get my pod to handle an SSL?

Comment: Yes, you can expose a new service on port 443.  Layer 7 is HTTP or HTTPS, layer 4 is TCP/UDP.

Comment: So I exposed a TCP service on port 443 and when I try to visit the https://... endpoint, I get the error `104.X.X.X unexpectedly closed the connection.` from within chrome. Do I need to setup an SSL for an exposed service?

Comment: Is the backend alive on the load balancer? is the healthcheck active?

Comment: I am also getting the error `104.X.X.X refused to connect`. Do I have to do something to configure an SSL? I am deploying my asp.net core project from Visual Studio using Google Cloud Tools, if that helps. I have a backend service that exists for the service, and it has 2 VM instances that are healthy. Once I expose a deployment as a service on port 443, is further action required?